# Как красиво изменить значение dp, не создавая новый файл?

Tags: android

У меня есть такой Drawable. И у меня есть 5 окон. Для каждого я использую этот drawable но с разными значениями radious dp.

Создавать для каждого свой drawable это не правильно. Да и кода много получится и читать потом не приятно будет. Можно ли как - то изменить этос наименьшим вариантом кода?

К примеру указать dp в dimens. Потом в 2 окне полуить этот dimens изменить значения и чтобы drawable изменил значение. Но попробов ничего не получилось)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/whiteBg"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно получить `shape` в виде `GradientDrawable` из фона/картинки вьюхи и назначать радиус программно так:

```
View view = ...;
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) view.getBackground();
shape.setCornerRadius(42);
```

Comment: Это все круто конечно. А через XML ни как не сделать?

Comment: @xTIGRx, ну, например можно переопределить вьюху, в которой этот фон используется, задать ей параметры, назначаемые через разметку. Так вы в разметке указываете число, а внутри переопределённой вьюхи оно из разметки достаётся и подставляется описанным в ответе образом.

Comment: Другими словами единственный варинат создать свою кастомную вьюху?

Comment: Ну, вам по-любому надо менять где-то значение. Сделать это можно только программно. Либо на стандартной вьюхе либо на кастомной. В первом случае не надо свою создавать. Во втором-можно через разметку задать или метод вызвать у этой вьюхи. Тут всё от задачи зависит как лучше

Comment: А вы не знаете готовые кастомные вьюхи всякие там TextView Button EdiText. Чтобы со вяскими примочками типо радиус можно было доабвтья. Картинки. Крутить их ит.д. Все в одном типо?

Comment: Нет, не слышал про такие

Answer (score 3):

Варианта два, либо наклепать ресурсов с разным радиусом, либо создавать их в коде.

```
GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
shape.setCornerRadius(<radius in pixels>);
shape.setColor(<argb color>);
```

Значения радиуса проще указать как dp в dimens и оттуда читать.

Для уменьшения кол-ва кода, создайте метод, который вам будет создавать shape с нужными параметрами и дергайте его. Как я понимаю, для вас достаточно вынести только радиус в параметр.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй создать array в ресурсах. В item записываешь значения радиусов, а уже програмно из каждого активити берешь нужный элемент массива.